# uppy how to add metaFields from Dashboard to XHRUpload

Tags: javascript, php, uppy

I use

```
"@uppy/core": "^1.13.2",
"@uppy/dashboard": "^1.12.8",
"@uppy/xhr-upload": "^1.6.4",
```

and Symfony in server side and I faced with some problem, `metaFields` not present in meta data file in server

I followed to example from doc. And my dashboard contains `metaFields` for files, name and caption, but when `XHRUpload` send request to server I got nothing about this keys in request in server. I added metaFields: null, like in doc - `Set this to null (the default) to send all metadata fields.`, but in server had empty about this keys, only `files`, `id` and `entity`
How to add `metaFields` from Dashboard to XHRUpload ?

```
    // Import the plugins
    const Uppy = require('@uppy/core')
    const XHRUpload = require('@uppy/xhr-upload')
    const Dashboard = require('@uppy/dashboard')
    let timeOfLastAttach = new Date();
    const uppy = Uppy({
        debug: true,
        autoProceed: false,
        restrictions: {
            maxFileSize: 100097152,//100Mb
        }          
    });
    uppy.use(Dashboard, {
        trigger: '.UppyModalOpenerBtn',
        inline: true,
        target: '.DashboardContainer',
        replaceTargetContent: true,
        showProgressDetails: true,
        note: 'add Images',
        height: 470,
        metaFields: [
            { id: 'name', name: 'Name', placeholder: 'file name' },
            { id: 'caption', name: 'Caption', placeholder: 'describe what the image is about' }
        ],
        browserBackButtonClose: true
    });
    uppy.setMeta({
        id: categoryId, entity: 'Entity\\Category'
    });
    uppy.use(XHRUpload, {
        endpoint: attachment_files,
        formData: true,
        fieldName: 'files[]',
        bundle: true,
        metaFields: null,
        getResponseData (responseText, response) {
            return {
                url: responseText
            }
        }
    });
```

this is what I have in request in browser

```
id: 112
entity: Entity\Category
files[]: (binary)
```

and in server files did not contains key `caption`

this what I have in files

```
files = {array} [5]
 name = {array} [1]
  0 = "Выделение_403.png"
 type = {array} [1]
  0 = "image/png"
 tmp_name = {array} [1]
  0 = "/tmp/phpmnkEMl"
 error = {array} [1]
  0 = {int} 0
 size = {array} [1]
  0 = {int} 145516
```

I try to create some test case

```
    uppy.on('file-added', (file) =>{
        console.log(file);
        uppy.setFileMeta(file.id, {
            test: 'hello'
        });
    });
```

and still in server side, `$_FILES['files']` did not contains `test` key.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Form plugin?
https://uppy.io/docs/transloadit/#fields